# How would I convert PNG to PDF in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart, png

Does anyone here know the pseudocode to convert a PNG image into a PDF file in Dart/Flutter??

Just the high level steps would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply convert a png to a pdf file. png is an image format and pdf is a document format.

That said, here is how you can do it:

1. Import the flutter [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package.
2. create a new pdf file using the package and insert your png image on a full size page.